# setter selectors does not autocomplete in swift

Tags: swift

How do I call the set methods in swift. They dont autocomplete
**For eg:**
 As per **NSProgressIndicator Class Reference**
it has 2 selectors `doubleValue` and `setDoubleValue`.
How do I call setDoubleValue, also it does not auto completes
Is it recommended to use obj.doubleValue to get and set the property ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it recommended to use obj.doubleValue to get and set the property?

It is not only recommended but actually necessary to call it like

```
obj.doubleValue
```

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSProgressIndicator_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSProgressIndicator/setDoubleValue:) states, in Swift the getter/setter is converted to

```
var doubleValue: Double
```

This is the case for pretty much every Objc-property.

Comment: Ok looks fine. But then what is setDoubleValue doing in the documentation ? Is is just there to explain the type of data to be assigned ?

Comment: It is still in there because it is still valid for Objc where the @property is just syntactic sugar for a getter, a setter and a backing storage variable.